# Android: StartActivityForResult causes StackOverFlow Error

Tags: android, listactivity, stack-overflow

I have a gridView that displays some icons (in a Main Menu format) - Based on the Icon pressed I need to launch an activity. I am doing this using a switch statement.

It works fine for two of my activities, however when I try to launch a third activity I get a StackOverFlow Error.

**StackTrace:**

```
07-11 11:32:44.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18842): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-11 11:32:44.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18842): java.lang.StackOverflowError
07-11 11:32:44.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18842):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
07-11 11:32:44.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18842):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
07-11 11:32:44.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18842):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2749)
07-11 11:32:44.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18842):     at com.***.NotesMainMenuActivity.startActivity(NotesMainMenuActivity.java:86)
07-11 11:32:44.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18842):     at com.***.NotesMainMenuActivity$1.onItemClick(NotesMainMenuActivity.java:45)
07-11 11:32:44.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18842):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
07-11 11:32:44.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18842):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1640)
07-11 11:32:44.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18842):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-11 11:32:44.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18842):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-11 11:32:44.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18842):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-11 11:32:44.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18842):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-11 11:32:44.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18842):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 11:32:44.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18842):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-11 11:32:44.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18842):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-11 11:32:44.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18842):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-11 11:32:44.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18842):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

StackTrace indicates that the offending lines are: 86 and 45.

**Line 45**

Line 45 is part of the OnClickListener where I call a method to choose which activity to start:

```
private void setClickListenter()
{
    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            startActivity(position);   <--- Line 45
        }
    }); 
}
```

**Line 86**

Line 86 is where I create an intent after to start the new Activity

```
    Intent i;

    switch(position)
    {
        case ITEM_CLICK_NEWNOTE:
            i = new Intent(this, NoteEditActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
            break;

        case ITEM_CLICK_VIEWNOTES:
            i = new Intent(this, NotesListActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, VIEW_NOTES);
            break;

        case ITEM_CLICK_RECYCLED:
            Log.w("MainMenuAdapter", "Got into Recycled Switch");
            i = new Intent(this, RecycledNotesListActivity.class);   <--- Line 86
            startActivityForResult(i, RECYCLED_NOTES);
            break;
    }
```

The top two parts of the switch statement ITEM_CLICK_NEWNOTE and ITEM_CLICK_VIEWNOTES work correctly - The activity starts as expected. Only ITEM_CLICK_RECYCLED causes an error. 
Based on throwing some Log lines into the code into RecycledNotesListActivity.java I don't believe any of the code in that runs. It breaks before then.

I'm confused because all three parts of the switch statement are the same, yet two work and one doesn't.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Hmmmm is the value for `ITEM_CLICK_RECYCLED` correct?

Comment: I believe so - Before the Crash i can see the Log Message I added on Line 85.
ITEM_CLICK_NEWNOTE, VIEWNOTES and RECYCLED are just 0,1,2 its the position value of the item in GridView that was clicked.

Comment: Ok.... stack overflow errors generally mean infinite recursion, but I can't see  any of that with just the snippets you posted.

Comment: Yeah - I've been reading up about them. I can't see anywhere where Infinite recursion could happen. 
The activity doesn't get launched - Well the Log line I added as the first line in OnCreate() doesn't show up in the Trace. 

Is there anyway to get more information from the Stack Trace?

Comment: Can anyone else help? 
I'm lost here!

Comment: Sorry mate, I'm out of ideas without looking at some more complete code :(

Comment: @Matt : hello, you already got the answer?

Comment: Please debug to know what's wrong. I think there is a loop in your method `startActivityForResult` or the other method.